# Cannot update ngModel value from component.ts more than once

Tags: angular, input, ngmodel, two-way-binding

I have an input field in html and I would like to clear it as soon as something is typed in it after performing some work on the value.
I am using ngModel for this. 
The issue is my code clears the value of the input field only the first time when I write something in it. After that it doesn't work.

receive.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input [(ngModel)]="donation_detail"  (ngModelChange)="fecthDetail()" 
  matInput placeholder=" code">
</mat-form-field>
```

receive.component.ts

```
fecthDetail(){
     console.log(this.donation_detail)
     //do something with the vlaue and then clear it
     this.donation_detail = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you added `(ngModelChange)` in your `<input>`, No change event binding is required in `ngModel`

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input [ngModel]="donation_detail"  (ngModelChange)="fecthDetail()" 
  matInput placeholder=" code">
</mat-form-field>
```